# GitHub Pages изменить ветку

Tags: git, github, git-branch, github-pages

Здравствуйте. Интересует такой вопрос, можно ли, чтобы GitHub Pages использовал другую ветку, на gh-pages, а, к примеру, master?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, это верно только для личных страниц пользователей и организаций. Для проектов же всегда используется ветка `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Это стандартное соглашение по [именованию веток страниц](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) проектов. Настройками оно не меняется.